# Reg Exp for URL that could be encoded

Tags: arrays, regex

I have a url schema like that: */users/orders/{orderId}*.
The *orderId* can contains letters, digits or is maybe url encoded.
e.g.:

- /users/orders/123
- /users/orders/ads
- /users/orders/13as
- /users/orders/34sl%3F

What I need is a Reg Exp that match the url schema.
I started with `^/users/orders/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`.
But I am missing something like or `%A-Z0-9` at the end.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just decode the url before matching the regex?

Comment: You could just add the `%` to your character class.

Comment: this works for me https://regex101.com/r/hR6yB5/1

Comment: the following will match most of the encoded characters i can think of:

/users/orders/([%\w !\^@<>-]*(&[glt]+;)*)+

Comment: @Bergi I cannot decode it before. And if i could what would i need to match all the chars and signs that are allowed.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, i tried it but forgot the escape sign. It also match /users/orders/34sl%%%%3F, is this a valid url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^\/users\/orders\/((?:[\w-]|\%\w{2})+)$` - demo @ [link](https://regex101.com/r/eQ1vK3/1).

`^\/users\/orders\/` -- the part of the URL before ORDERID, anchored to the beginning of the line.

`[\w-]` -- equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`.

`\%\w{2}` -- a `%` sign, followed by two instances of `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

`((?:[\w-]|\%\w{2})+)$` -- one or more instances of the previous two patterns, captured and anchored to the end of the line.